# COM Component in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, com

I have a WCF service which is using a COM component. The clients of WCF service are making calls to set the properties in the COM object and then calling other methods on the object to retrieve results. I want to keep the data in the COM object safe from other clients. Client should only read the values that they have set. Can someone please advise whether this can be achieved in WCF? I tried playing around with InstanceMode and ConcurrencyMode but that doesn't help.

Comment: Good question. My understanding of COM is that its marshaled, but are you actually talking about keeping the Values written by client A safe from client B? That would seem to be something you have to handle in the COM component wouldn't it?

Comment: Is it an out-of-proc COM server? Otherwise, what is the threading model for in-proc COM object? If you COM object has to maintains a state, you'd probably be looking to make your WCF service a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx).

Comment: The component is a DLL (in process) developed by a third party.  So, I cannot do any modification to it.

Comment: Then force the third party to live up to the requirements. There are many ways you can add state to a WCF service; InstanceMode is one way (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx), you can cache data or add it to a database. It all depends on the requirements.